# zip directory with dedicate childfolders

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm trying to pack a folder directory into a zip directory, not including all child folders.

currently i m using this method to pack the whole directory.

```
public void directoryPacker(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
   string pathToRootDirectory = Path.Combine(directoryInfo.Parent.FullName,
                               directoryInfo.Name) + ".abc"; //name of root file
   using(ZipContainer zip = new ZipContainer(pass)) 
   //ZipContainer inherits from Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
   {
       //some password stuff here
       //
       //zipping
       zip.AddDirectory(directoryInfo.FullName, "/"); //add complete subdirectory to *.abc archive (zip archive)
       File.Delete(pathToRootDirectory);
       zip.Save(pathToRootDirecotry); //save in rootname.bdd
   }
}
```

this works really great, but now i have a

```
 List<string> paths
```

within the paths to the childfolders which i want to have in my zipArchive. The other childfolders(not in the list) should not be in the archive

thank you

Comment: why not simply create a foreach-loop over your paths and call `directoryPacker()` for every path?

Comment: because i do something else in the directoryPacker() and dont need this for childfolders...only for the root directory

Comment: DO you have seperate functions for childfolders and rootfolders then?

Comment: no, i thought i can solve it in one function

Comment: Could you post the full code of your directoryPacker() then? It is hard to figure out what you are doing without it

Comment: i ve edited my post, hope it will help to understand the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any built in function that adds folder non-recursively. So I wrote a function that adds them manually:

```
public void directoryPacker(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    // The list of all subdirectory relatively to the rootDirectory, that should get zipped too
    var subPathsToInclude = new List<string>() { "subdir1", "subdir2", @"subdir2\subsubdir" };

    string pathToRootDirectory = Path.Combine(directoryInfo.Parent.FullName,
                                directoryInfo.Name) + ".abc"; //name of root file
    using (ZipContainer zip = new ZipContainer(pass))
    //ZipContainer inherits from Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
    {
        // Add contents of root directory
        addDirectoryContentToZip(zip, "/", directoryInfo.FullName);

        // Add all subdirectories that are inside the list "subPathsToInclude"
        foreach (var subPathToInclude in subPathsToInclude)
        {
            var directoryPath = Path.Combine(new[] { directoryInfo.FullName, subPathToInclude });
            if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                addDirectoryContentToZip(zip, subPathToInclude.Replace("\\", "/"), directoryPath);
            }
        }


        if (File.Exists(pathToRootDirectory))
            File.Delete(pathToRootDirectory);

        zip.Save(pathToRootDirecotry); //save in rootname.bdd
    }
}

private void addDirectoryContentToZip(ZipContainer zip, string zipPath, DirectoryInfo directoryPath)
{
    zip.AddDirectoryByName(zipPath);
    foreach (var file in directoryPath.GetFiles())
    {
        zip.AddFile(file, zipPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FullName));
    }
}
```

I did not test it, can you tell me if this works for you?